# SSIS How to pass a variable in as script source

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to find a way of passing in the source (or at least some dynamic source) into an SSIS Script task.

The reason behind is is I have an SSIS engine that reads dynamic steps from the database (mainly SQL script or stored procedure) and I want to add some steps that are C# based. It is not really feasible to edit a script job in the package every time something new comes up so was wondering if anyone had a way of suppling the source dynamically. That way I can just add the script source in the db and read it into an SSIS variable and then execute.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to do this with straight SSIS, but you could look into using BIML Script to dynamically create your packages based on the dynamic steps in your database.   It's probably the closest thing possible to what you want.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for your input. I have already started on a dll containing an IStep interface in which I can dynamically create the classes through reflection. This means I can pass the Assembly name to create into the script task and call the approriate interface methods.